# File Not Found Exception was unhandled in the line of adapter.Fill(table)

Tags: c#, mysql, ado.net, filenotfoundexception

Im trying to connect to the database MySql but this error was appeared

> FileNotFoundException was unhandled

in the line of `adapter.Fill`.

FileNotFoundException was unhandled Could not load file or assembly 'Renci.SshNet, Version=2016.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1cee9f8bde3db106' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified

```
class CONNECT
{
    private MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection("Datasource=localhost;Port=3306;Username=root;Password=;Database=Csharp_Hotel_DB");

    //create a function to return our connection
    public MySqlConnection getConnection()
    {
        return connection;
    }

    //create a function to open the connection
    public void openConnection()
    {
        if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
        {
            connection.Open();

        }
    }

    //create a function to close the connection
    public void closeConnection()
    {
        if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            connection.Close();

        }
    }
}

private void buttonLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CONNECT conn = new CONNECT();
    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter();
    MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand();
    String query = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username`=@usn AND `password`=@pass";

    command.CommandText = query;
    command.Connection = conn.getConnection();

    command.Parameters.Add("@usn", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = textBoxUsername.Text;
    command.Parameters.Add("@pass", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = textBoxPassword.Text;

    adapter.SelectCommand = command;
    adapter.Fill(table); //this line is the FileNotFoundException was unhandled


    // if the username and the password exists
    if (table.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        this.Hide();
        MessageBox.Show("YES");
        Main_Form mform = new Main_Form();
        mform.Show();
    }
    else
    {

        if (textBoxUsername.Text.Trim().Equals(""))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Enter Your Username to Login", "Empty Username", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
        else if (textBoxPassword.Text.Trim().Equals(""))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Enter Your Password to Login", "Empty Password", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
        else
        { 
            MessageBox.Show("Username and Password Doesn't Exists", "Wrong Data", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share the code of `conn.getConnection()` and also the connection string of mysql database?

Comment: Done edit please help me

Comment: please see the edited code i include the conn.getConnection()

Comment: Can you share the complete message of the exception. The message should say which file not found. It would be helpful to now which file is not found to suggest the solution

Comment: FileNotFoundException was unhandled

Could not load file or assembly 'Renci.SshNet, Version=2016.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1cee9f8bde3db106' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: the line of adapter.Fill(table) that line is the FileNotFoundException was unhandled

Comment: As per the exception you need to in add reference to `Renci.SshNet` in your project. That library is being used when connecting to MySQL.

Comment: Looks like this is a known issue with MySqlConnector.... https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?38,677418,678143#msg-678143 You need to use one lower version of connector to resolve this issue... you can read it in the link

Comment: Thank you for your help.  using the old version of MySQL connector can fix this error or problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems that you do not handle the exceptions adapter.fill could through.
use:

```
try{
    adapter.Fill(table);
} catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
    do stuff with e or your code
}
```

alternatively check the pathes if they exist before using them.

Comment: i need help . control my computer please with using "teamviewer"

Comment: i don't think so. 

just try the try catch block or check the path to your files/database with an if statement before using them.

Answer (score 1):

It's now working c.
Using the `MySQL-connector-net-6.3.5` can fix this error or problem because I'm using .net 4

Thank you for your help.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. You can [search for similar questions](//stackoverflow.com/search), or refer to the related and linked questions on the right-hand side of the page to find an answer. If you have a related but different question, [ask a new question](//stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), and include a link to this one to help provide context. See: [Ask questions, get answers, no distractions](//stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a data table without passing a name into the constructor. This means that the table is nameless and so when you try to call Fill on a nameless table you get your file not found exception.

You should pass in the table name

`DataTable table = new DataTable("users");`

Comment: still FileNotFoundException  was unhandled

Comment: i need help . control my computer please with using "teamviewer"

Comment: I don't think this statement is true *"when you try to call Fill on a nameless table you get your file not found exception"*. I always create DataTable without a name and never run into trouble

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in MySQL Connector/NET, [bug 96614](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=96614). It will be fixed in Connector/NET 8.0.18.

> Fixed as of the upcoming MySQL Connector/NET 8.0.18 release, and here's the changelog entry:
>
> The Renci.SshNet.dll deployment was problematic for Connector/NET 8.0.17
>   MSI installations. Some applications, such as Microsoft Excel, were unable
>   to read MySQL data as a result. This fix removes unnecessary dependencies
>   on the DLL and also ensures that the MSI installation deploys the correct
>   Renci.SshNet.dll to the GAC.

A workaround you can use today is switching to [MySqlConnector](https://mysqlconnector.net), an alternative OSS ADO.NET library for MySQL, which doesn't have this bug.